# How can I execute commands from an SDK on a html site?

Tags: php, html, linux, terminal, sdk

I hope you can give me some information and solutions about a problem which Im struggling right now:

Im working on a linux machine and I have a software development kit installed on this machine, which is written in C. If you have started the SDK in a linux-terminal you have a few options/commands which you can execute in the SDK. Commands could be "start", "stop", "restart" or "pause".

Now, I want to execute this commands on a html site.

I know, that I can execute the sdk in a php-script via (shell_exec('...'), but I dont know how to excute the commands in the SDK via the php-script.

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what you are talking about? Which SDK you are talking about?

Comment: Its an SDK from anki-Overdrive. It is a toy, where speed cars are driven from this sdk: https://github.com/anki/drive-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow @codingguy.

The question you're looking for is how to write to stdin of a subprocess.

You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5443250/3743020) another used asked. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @N.D.
I will take a look.